# Rolling back a transaction in Spring ApplicationListener

Tags: spring, transactions, listener

Normal Spring `ApplicationListner`s are running synchronously within the same thread of the event publisher.

Is there any way to rollback the main context transaction in the listener?

I have a method annotated `@Transactional` and it publishes an event, I want to make execute the listeners in the scope of the main method, and rollback the main transaction in case of exceptions.

I am using a LocalTransactionManager on Hibernate SessionFactory.

Is there any way to do this using Spring 3.3.x?

Comment: I believe you have to register your own transaction synchronization through the manager and just handle it manually. This process is simplified via annotations in Spring 4.2+

Comment: Well in my `ApplicationListener` I injected the TransactionTemplate and inside a `TransactionCallback` I called `setRollbackOnly()`, but nothing good happens!